# Animating background-position:bottom not possible with Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari

I have a situation where I need to animate a background-image's y property from a pixel dimension to 'bottom' via CSS animation. While this works fine in Chrome and FF, it does not appear to work in Safari. I've also tried '100%' which again works in Chrome and FF but not in Safari.

I've dug around online a fair bit but can't find any definitive documentation that sets out that Safari does not support animating this property to bottom but that appears to be its behaviour.

Can anyone shed any light on this - and/or confirm this really isn't possible?

Here is a fiddle to test it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/coalescent/GRgAV/1/

```
@-webkit-keyframes mastheadBG {
    0% { background-position-y: 300px; }
    100% { background-position-y: bottom; }
}

.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height:30%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    background-image: url(http://coalescentdesign.com/_img/circle.png);
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-animation: mastheadBG 3.0s ease;
}
```

Unfortunately, I need to achieve the animation like this because the containing element has a variable height - and I would prefer to not resort to using any js.

Thanks,
Mike